# DIVs with child P-elements - Where does this margin come from?

Tags: html, css

I've got three divs within a wrapper-div.

Containing no child-elements the divs behave as expected: Every div comes after it's preceding sibling. With no margin between them.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.rect {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.orange {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, pink, orange);
}

.orange p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">   
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect orange"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Now I've added two paragraphs into the second div.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.rect {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.orange {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, pink, orange);
}

.orange p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">   
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect orange">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
      Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget
      dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

Now do I get these margin between the first and the second div.

[image: Margin between first and second div.]

Beside the top- and bottom-margin of the wrapper: There are no margins defined in any way.

**Where does these margin come from?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where does the margin come from?**

- Browsers use css defaults.
- If you do not specify code then the defaults are used.
- Defaults differ for each browser. It is good
  practice to always reset (Default) all common values at the start of
  your stylesheet.

**Why do margins have this effect?**

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

This means nested elements with margins will add their margins to the conatining element.

---

Below I have added a reset for the margin value:

```
p { margin:0; }
```

However you should use a full reset to prevent defaults being applied.

```css
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLOBAL RESET
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, p, th, td, a, em, img, strong, ul, li, form, label, h1, h2, h3, h4{margin:0; padding:0; border:none;}
:focus{outline:none;}
html{box-sizing:border-box;}
*,*::before, *::after{box-sizing:inherit;}
html,body,form{height:100%;position:relative;}


html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1.0);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.rect {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.orange {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, pink, orange);
}

.orange p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">   
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect orange">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.
      Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget
      dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
      nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>
```

---

### CSS RESET

There are many resets already available on the web. A popular one being however I recommend you customise a reset to only use applied values.

**[MEYERS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

**SIMPLE RESET**

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, p, th, td, a, em, img, strong, ul, li, form, label, h1, h2, h3, h4{margin:0; padding:0; border:none;}
:focus{outline:none;}
html{box-sizing:border-box;}
*,*::before, *::after{box-sizing:inherit;}
html,body,form{height:100%;position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `<p>`  tags have default margins
2. If a `<p>` tag is inside a `div` element which has no margins, the "outside" margins of the `p` will be added to the `div`.